# Passing data from stored procedure to a VBScript

Tags: sql, vbscript, sqltransaction

I have a stored procedure which among all the data get a date range from a website form. This stored procedure is calling a vbs I created which is supposed to unzip some files where their naming is based on the date they were created.

The question I have is how can I pass the date range to variables in the vbs to do its job?

I.e.: date range is `25 to 27 Jan 2016`, the sql need to pass to the vbs `25012015` and `27012016`.

After a bit of research I saw you can pass data from vbs to the stored procedure so i am looking for doing the other way around.

I did not post any code as I m looking for something generic as both my script are working fine apart for passing the data from stored procedure to VBS.

Comment: You should post some code !

Comment: the idea is very basic even if I could not find how to do it. if I have a variable containing a date, how can I pass it to the VbS I a calling so I don't see what code to even display as the code does not have any issues

Comment: How you got this range of date from 25 to 27 Jan 2016 by your code ?

Comment: they re obtained by a web form. 2 variables are sent by the form: from and to.

Comment: Are you executing the SP via an ADODB object?  If so, which one?